# Opening a vagrant server for MySQL

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, vagrant

## Introduction

I am a php developer. I use vagrant for approximate replication of live server environments.

I have many non-framework projects running, for example: simple addons, composer repositories and code snippets. These often require interaction with a database.

Instead of having 10s, possibly 100s of VMs (all taking up hard drive space), I would like to simply have a single Vagrant instance.

Now, normally this would be easy enough, but I do not want to map folders or such like. I simply want:

- a vagrant machine (currently I have a blank one running Ubuntu server)
- mySQL installed (it is)
- this MySQL to be available by non SSL methods

Other points:

- this does not need to be secure: this is a test/dump/rebuild server
- no real data will be used, only test data
- this will only be available locally

PHP can't tunnel easily, and the use case for all the code is to be used locally.

I'm a dev, not a server expert: I think I should be opening a port and passing through, but as I said: I'm no expert. It was a bit of a realisation that I've never had to do it the "insecure"/non SSL way before!

Thus... to get to the end of a long introduction:

## Question

How do I expose MySQL insecurely within an ubuntu vagrant environment?

- I should be able to run a local PHP script that uses no SSL
- I don't want to totally rebuild the vagrant server: I just want the commands/steps to open it

Example PHP login params array:

```
$connection_params = array(
'database' => 'cool_database',
'username' => 'open_database',
'password' => 'open_database_password',
'host' => 'domain-in-hosts-file.com',
'driver' => 'mysql',
);
```

### Current steps taken

Following several tutorials as follows:

- edited: `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` changed `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0`
- `sudo systemctl restart mysql.service`

Logged into mysql:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'open_database'@'192.168.55.1' IDENTIFIED BY "open_database_password" WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

(usernames/passwords and ipaddress changed as this is a forum :) )

### Edit: Answers to questions

`netstat` output:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Comment: What error do you get in PHP when connecting with these params? You could name your MySQL user `'open_database'@'%'` to have no origin restrictions at all. Did you check with `netstat` that MySQL is really binding on 0.0.0.0 ?

Comment: PHP is running outside the VM on your host machine, right?

Comment: Yes. PHP is not the issue. The error is a connection error, not a php error. Looking at `netstat` and renaming user now.

Comment: PHP may not be the issue, but you must get an error from it. Otherwise what is your problem / how do you tell there is one? I'd like to see the PDO/mysqli error message that occurs while connecting.

Comment: I know that php is not the issue. I can copy the php connection error if you need that, but in order to debug I am using phpStorm's database module. It has the same connectivity problem:

Comment: Question updated to include netstat output.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear there, you should have checked `netstat -ltnp` (`l` for listening) to show the listening ports.

Comment: Modified as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After combining/translating some blog posts, garnering the stuff I needed from each:

## Answer

Here are the steps to open mysql on a vagrant or similar connection.

### Port opening

Vagrant does not pass through the port by default. This can be done by as follows:

- Vagrantfile style: `config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3306`
- config.yaml style:

  ```
                      portmysql:
                          host: '3306'
                          guest: '3306'
  ```

### Modify MySQL config

Edit `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`:

- comment out `skip-external-locking`
- comment out `bind-address`

These two items stop mysql from listening to external addresses etc.

Restart MySQL:

- `sudo service mysql restart`

### Set up users

- Run `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'%'`;
- FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

### End!

Hopefully that will help you.

The main problem is that no individual blog I've read actually explained all the items. So to recap:

- open a port (3306 usually)
- set mysql to listen to this port (external-locking and bind-address)
- set up/modify a user to be actually able to read it (.. @'%')

Hope that helps someone else.